# SQL - count (*) not working

Tags: sql, oracle, count

i want to use a simple `count(*)` code but there is something wrong.

```
select fname,lname, dno, count(*) from employee group by dno having count(*);
```

I am getting the following error:

> ERROR at line 4: ORA-00920: invalid relational operator

thank you very much!!

Comment: Before asking a question on SO, try read about constructions you use, often questions like this have trivial syntax errors.

Answer (score 2):

For a group operation to be performed, you need to mention the column names in the group by clause.

So the final query for you would be :

```
select fname,lname, dno, count(*) from employee group by dno,fname,lname;
```

Hope this helps. :)

Answer (score 1):

This query has two problems:
1. Invalid use of **group by** operator
2. Syntax error in **having** clause.

**For step1:** **Group by** clause to be used, make sure you have all columns in group by clause which you are mentioning in select statement. 
Biggest demerit of this way is, This grouping makes sub groups and using function like **count(*)** becomes senseless.

ex- If you have total 10 record of which 2 unique record in "**dno**" and "**lname**" is completely unique(which will be obvious practically). Then using group by dno,lname will create total of 10 groups and **count(*)** will return 1,1,1 value for each one of them. Actual need of group by got lost just to make query run.

So be careful.

**For step2** : correct syntax is having count(*)>1 or count(*)=2 or anything you want but complete it.

To preserve your logical requirement, you can use analytical function like below:

```
select e1.fname,e1.lname,e1.dno from 
(select fname,lname, dno, count(*) over (partition by dno) as cnt 
from employee) e1
where e1.cnt>1;
```

**e.cnt>1** in above query is my assumption. use it as per your need.

Answer (score 0):

No need for "having"

```
select fname,lname, dno, count(*) from employee group by dno;
```

Comment: Not sure this got upvoted, it's not valid Oracle syntax

Answer (score 0):

You should have an expression for `having` clause.

Try

```
select fname,lname, dno, count(*) from employee group by dno having count(*) > 0;
```

Also I think @Timur is right, there is no need for you to even have the `having clause` , `group by` is sufficient

Comment: if i try  
select fname,lname, dno, count(*) from employee group by dno;
it still have an error
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression

Answer (score 0):

```
select fname,lname, dno, count(*) 
from employee 
group by dno,fname,lname;
```

Answer (score 0):

your have missed few column name in group by , also having should have the relational operator.
please try

> select fname,lname, dno, count(1) from employee group by fname,lname,
>   dno having count(1)>=1;